# How to change the name "data-original" attribute name in images with no ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Context: I am trying a workaround to the lazyload script that does not work well for my setup.

I am not sure this is realistic but, this is what I have in mind:
On a title section click, I want to change all the attributes of the images contained in the section (so the images show).

From data-original to src.

Here is were I am:

```
$('#s101').click(function(){

var a = $('#b01').next().find('img').attr("data-original");

// alert (a) // will give me the url of the attr. data-original: (http...)

x = a.getAttribute("data-original");
a.setAttribute("src", x);
a.removeAttribute("data-original");
                          });
```

This does not work. Could you help?

Comment: `a` is a string, not a DOM element, why are you calling `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using an old version of jQuery, but the correct syntax for getting and setting attributes is a little different than what you're using.  use `.attr("attribute here")` to get attributes and `.attr("attribute here","value here")` to set attributes.

Comment: @SgtAJ He's mixing jQuery and DOM functions.

Comment: Yes, that's why I need help, I do not master all the concepts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#b01').next().find('img').each(function(){
   $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-original") ).removeAttr("data-original");
});
```

Comment: Try to get $('#b01').next().find('img').length in console. May be you have wrong search img condition

Comment: You are right it is undefined, funny because this will give me the proper value in console log. : var a = $('#b01').next().find('img').attr("data-original");

Comment: Correction: I have 3 images in this section, and it works for the 2nd image it changes this <img alt="" class="Photo lazy" data-original="http://ww.xxx.com/i/5/p/b02.jpg" src="http://place7.com/t.png" />

Comment: to this! so it works for the 2nd instance : <img class="Photo lazy" alt="" src="http://www.xxxxx.com/i/5/p/b02.jpg">

Comment: You were completely right, I had an issue, I fixed it this way: $('#s101').children().next().find('img').each(function(){

Answer (score 1):

Following along with your "click" handler methodology, you'd want to do something like this...

```
$("#btnChangeImage").click(function(){
    var a = $("#myImg");

    var x = a.attr("data-original");
    a.attr("src", x);
    a.removeAttr("data-original");
```

});

Basically, the problem is you're trying to act on an attribute and not an element, and then once you have that attribute you seem to be using an old jQuery API version.

Here's a quick plunk to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/3kZGz5kDLwaBDmGFzsWU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to understand